# ラムダ式に変数をキャプチャする方法

Tags: c++

ラムダ式に変数をコピーで入れたいのですが、関数でインスタンス作成やコピーするようなクラスの場合、ラムダ式に入れる際に何かいい方法があるでしょうか？

```
T a(T::create_instance());　 // インスタンス作成 
T b(T::create_instance());
b.copy(a);                  // aからbへコピー

  // ラムダ式
  auto func = [b]  <----- bではコピーコンストラクタがないためエラーになります。
  { 
     // 処理
  };
  int ret = func();
```

Comment: 具体例がないので状況がよく分かりませんが、ムーブコンストラクタはあるでしょうから、C++14であれば[初期化キャプチャ](https://cpprefjp.github.io/lang/cpp14/initialize_capture.html)が使えませんか？ [(Wandbox example)](https://wandbox.org/permlink/vTjJiSVD71MZYtTU)

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
何とか使えました！

Answer (score 1):

コメント欄でご回答いただいた、[初期化キャプチャ](https://cpprefjp.github.io/lang/cpp14/initialize_capture.html) にて解決しました。
ありがとうございます。